# How to trigger Airflow DAG independent runs with an ExternalTaskSensor

Tags: airflow

I built two DAGs(dag_a, dag_b) and create an ExternalTaskSensor in dag_b that pokes on dag_a. And there are two use cases for these DAGs:

1. schedule dag_a and dag_b at the same time and use the dependency to process dag_a first and then dag_b
2. manually trigger dag_b independently without caring about dag_a.

With an ExternalTaskSensor, use case 1 works pretty well. But use case 2 won't work. And the dag_b will stop at ExternalTaskSensor for dag_a and poke forever. Is there a way to skip ExternalTaskSensor with some conditions and run dag_b independently?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by using a `execution_date_fn` to check whether the DAG run was manually triggered, and raising an `AirflowSkipException` if so. The sensor task will be skipped when the DAG is manually triggered.

Tested on Airflow 2.1.

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSkipException
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context
from airflow.sensors.external_task import ExternalTaskSensor


def get_execution_date(execution_date):
    context = get_current_context()
    if context["dag_run"].external_trigger:
        raise AirflowSkipException
    
    return execution_date


default_dag_args = {
    "schedule_interval": "* * * * *",
    "start_date": datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    "catchup": False,
}

with DAG(dag_id="dag_a", **default_dag_args) as dag_a:
    dummy_task = DummyOperator(task_id="dummy_task")

with DAG(dag_id="dag_b", **default_dag_args) as dag_b:
    await_dag_a = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id="await_dag_a",
        external_dag_id="dag_a.v1",
        execution_date_fn=get_execution_date,
    )
    
    dummy_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id="dummy_task",
        # enable task to trigger even if parent task is skipped
        trigger_rule="none_failed",
    )

    await_dag_a >> dummy_task
```

Answer (score 0):

Since *Airflow 2.0.0*, I think there is no need to use `ExternalTaskSensor`. Using `TriggerDagRunOperator`, you could create and schedule a DAG that acts as a controller, having two tasks responsible for triggering DAG_A and DAG_B.

With the `wait_for_completion` param you could achieve your use case number one without affecting the possibility to trigger *DAG_B* independently. You could also specify the desire `poke_interval` and *allowed or failed* states.

[Docs:](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html)

> - wait_for_completion (bool) -- Whether or not wait for dag run completion. (default: False)
> - poke_interval (int) -- Poke interval to check dag run status when wait_for_completion=True. (default: 60)
> - allowed_states (list) -- list of allowed states, default is ['success']
> - failed_states (list) -- list of failed or dis-allowed states, default is None

Here is a link to the [example DAG](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_controller_dag.py) provide with Airflow.